# How to load scripts using a foreach loop with an array?

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to load scripts through the PowerShell profile by using a for loop, a path and an array of file names. Even though the full file path is correct in the variable, and the available commands are displayed to the PowerShell window, the scripts don't load their functions.

Note: the scripts do work when they are ran in this fashion `. C:\scripts\script.ps1`.

```
$PublicScripts   = "\\fileserver\scripts"
$PersonalScripts = "C:\scripts"

$commandArrayPersonal = @("adremove-pc.ps1", "template.ps1")
$commandArrayPublic   = @("get-pc.ps1",
    "port-commands.ps1",
    "LaptopNameChangeScript\adrenamepc-csv.ps1",
    "LaptopNameChangeScript\PingPC-csv.ps1",
    "remove-pc.ps1")

. C:\scripts\adremove-pc.ps1

function loopsForCommand([string]$path, [array]$commands) {
    foreach ($command in $commands) {
        $pathCommand = "$path\$command"

        if ((Test-Path $pathCommand)) {
            . "$pathCommand"
            Write-Host $command
        } else {
            Write-Host "Unavaliable: " $command
        }
    }
}

"`r`n** *  *  * **`r`nScripts Available for use:`r`n"
loopsForCommand -path $PublicScripts -commands $commandArrayPublic
loopsForCommand -path $PersonalScripts -commands $commandArrayPersonal
"`r`n** *  *  * **`r`n"
```

EDIT: lost some code in translation, removed `if($command.Contains("LaptopNameChangeScript")){` to narrow down the issue.

Comment: There is a brace missing for the function? I should hope your call is not recursive

Comment: Thank you @matt .I removed the brace. That was my fault when I transferred the code over.

Comment: Thank you @AnsgarWiechers i removed an irrelevant line from the code I posted. That was my fault when I transferred the code over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function call needed to be prefixed with a `.`:

```
. loopsForCommand -path $PublicScripts -commands $commandArrayPublic
. loopsForCommand -path $PersonalScripts -commands $commandArrayPersonal
```